# Java for-loop goes into minus?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist, negative-number

In my Programm I want to delete all items from an array, where the hd is not between temp_unten and temp_oben, but the for-loop goes to -1 and gives me this fail (I marked the line with an '^'):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

```
    if (hd) {
        int temp_unten = Integer.parseInt(spnHDUnten.getValue() + "");
        int temp_oben = Integer.parseInt(spnHDOben.getValue() + "");

        switch (cmbHDOben.getSelectedItem() + "") {
            case "MB":

                break;

            case "GB":
                temp_oben = temp_oben * 1000;
                break;

            case "TB":
                temp_oben = temp_oben * 1000 * 1000;
                break;
        }
        switch (cmbHDUnten.getSelectedItem() + "") {
            case "MB":

                break;

            case "GB":
                temp_unten = temp_unten * 1000;
                break;

            case "TB":
                temp_unten = temp_unten * 1000 * 1000;
                break;
        }

        if (!(temp_oben < temp_unten)) {
            for (int i = zutreffendeObjektnummern.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                for (int i2 = GUI.objekte_objekt_ID.size() - 1; i >= 0; i2--) {
     ^              if (!(GUI.hd.get(i2).replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+", "").equalsIgnoreCase("")) && Integer.parseInt(GUI.objekte_objekt_ID.get(i2).replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+", "")) == Integer.parseInt(zutreffendeObjektnummern.get(i).replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+", ""))) { 

                        if (Integer.parseInt(GUI.hd.get(i2).replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+", "")) < temp_unten || Integer.parseInt(GUI.hd.get(i2).replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+", "")) > temp_oben) {
                            zutreffendeObjektnummern.remove(i);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Von/Bis muss beim Auswahlen von Spannen beachtet werden!", "Fehlerhafte Eingabe", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

    }
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You mistake `i` for `i2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner for loop condition should use `i2` instead of `i`. It should look something like this:

```
for (int i2 = GUI.objekte_objekt_ID.size() - 1; i2 >= 0; i2--)
```

Comment: Thank you :) I searched everywehre but i haven't seen this fail.